# Why are React keys limited to strings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, when rendering a mapping from elements of a list/array/iterable to React elements, we're required to attach a locally-unique key to each element.  Generally this is so that if an element changes or is removed, React only needs to rerender that specific element rather than the whole list.  This key is required to be a string, and if an element-specific key is not forthcoming, there is an npm package* ([shortid](https://github.com/dylang/shortid)) for generating them.

Why did the React designers set this requirement rather than allowing any immutable value?  In particular, it makes sense to me to be able to use a [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol), which cannot be converted to a unique string.  (Upon re-examining my specific case where I wanted to use a `Symbol`, I realized it was unnecessary, but the question still stands in general.)

---

* There also used to be a package specifically designed for this called `react-key-index` but it seems to have disappeared from github.

Comment: [Symbol.keyFor(Symbol.for("tokenString")) == "tokenString"; // true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol)

Comment: @candied_orange that method can convert a Symbol to a string, but it defeats the purpose of the Symbol. The idea behind this question is that `key="Foo"` and `key={Symbol('Foo')}` could represent different items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React writes the key to the HTML and reads it back when parsing the DOM.

Since the HTML attribute is a string, whatever value you give it must be serialised to a string.

If you wanted to use non strings you would require a de/serialiser and possibly a second attribute in the HTML element to indicate the type of the key value.

Also remember this is essentially an optimisation so we don't have to re generate the entire HTML on every change. So anything that would slow the process down would be undesirable.

Comment: This might have been true in the past, but if you inspect the element tree in your browser, you'll see that no such attribute gets written to the HTML.

Comment: jeeze 2018 seems so long ago. maybe i was just wrong? you should add a new answer

Comment: excellent suggestion

Answer (score 6):

### Up-to-date as of 2021

They're not, but the React docs encourage the use of strings over any other type. Any data type will "work" (except `undefined` as @theHutt points out).

This is because React coerces your key *into* a string before storing it for future reconciliations. It does so with a simple concatenation (essentially `key = '' + key`).

The sanest type to concatenate like this is another string. So long as, in the case of an array of React elements, the resulting string is unique amongst the elements, it'll work.

Here's a link to the source code.

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/90e5d3638844414e1b9df0fe66c3fc46b211d210/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L224-L236

Comment: `undefined` doesn't work

Comment: @theHutt Good catch!